# Google Vision Python 2.7 TypeError: construct_settings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metrics_headers'

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, vision

After installing the required packages using pip, downloading a Json key and setting the enviroment variable in the cmd window with: set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'C:\Users\ xxx .json' and following the instructions to use the Google Vision API on https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision-usage.html#authentication-and-configuration

I tried the following and got the following error without any idea how to solve the error, so all suggestions are much appreciated

```
>>> from google.cloud import vision
>>> client =vision.Client()
>>> print client
<google.cloud.vision.client.Client object at 0x08D414F0>
>>> image =  client.image(filename='test2.jpg')
>>> print image
<google.cloud.vision.image.Image object at 0x0CBF68F0>
>>> text = image.detect_text()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\image.py", line 289, in detect_text
    annotations = self.detect(features)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\image.py", line 143, in detect
    return self._detect_annotation(images)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\image.py", line 117, in _detect_annotation
    return self.client._vision_api.annotate(images)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\client.py", line 114, in _vision_api
    self._vision_api_internal = _GAPICVisionAPI(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\_gax.py", line 34, in __init__
    lib_version=__version__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\gapic\vision\v1\image_annotator_client.py", line 140, in __init__
    metrics_headers=metrics_headers, )
TypeError: construct_settings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metrics_headers'
```

Comment: Was this resolved for you.

Comment: No unfortunately not ....

Comment: I have the same problem. Figured its because of conflictions with python libraries . You could check using `pipconflictchecker` which gives conflictions with google cloud python libraries . Not resolved yet though.